# Seaborn's pairplot seems to have scalling issue on diagonal plots

Tags: python, seaborn

Here is the code I tested

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.pairplot(tips)
```

By default, the diagonal plots are all histograms, and everything seems right (see the picgure below).
[image]

However, when I change the setting of pairplot function to something like below, the scale of the vertical axis of the histograms shrinks while the shape and number of bins are still the same (see the picture below). Does anyone know what happened here? I checked the documentation of the pairplot (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html), by default, the `diag_kind` is set to 'auto'. When the `kind` parameter is equal to `scatter` (the default setting too), even though `diag_kind` equals to `auto`, it will be reset to `hist` behind the scene (https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L1822). So technically the two scripts I presented here should produce the same histograms. Totally lost here ...

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips', diag_kind='hist')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is that the diagonal plots will only share the Y with the rest of the row if `diag_kind == 'hist'`. When `diag_kind == 'auto'`, the `diag_sharey` parameter to `PairGrid` is set to `False`.

I see you're already opened an issue about it on Seaborn's github. I guess a clarification of this behaviour (principle of least astonishment, etc.) in the doc string for `diag_kind` would be helpful.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/211cabb09bb9228635bdd80f74f7591d36d7b2a7/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L1924) is the relevant line of code (I think it would be useful to include that to your answer).